# Using Macros in Google Documents - is it possible?

Tags: google-docs, google-apps-script

I want to be able to have some macros, while writing in a Google Document.

The idea is to replace the [Quick Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/quick-parts-HA010370568.aspx#BM1) in Word - so I can have the same functionality in a Google Document.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Introduction

Google [lately](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2013/05/new-apps-script-features-at-google.html) added the Google Apps Script functionality in Google Documents and presented some [basics](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#the_basics) on the Google Developers site.

One key feature is the sidebar. This is where the "Quick Parts" could reside. It needs however a bit of coding to do that. See the following example, made by [Martin Hawksey](https://plus.google.com/114662816634467534305/posts): [Sidebar](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2013/05/playing-with-google-docs-sidebar-using-google-apps-script/:)

Update 27/07/2013, here's an example I wrote myself:

### Code

```
// global
var app = DocumentApp.getUi();

function onOpen() {
  app.createMenu('Quick Parts')
    .addItem('Document Property', 'docProperty').addToUi();
}

function docProperty() {
  // set variables
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
  var fileName = doc.getName(), Id = doc.getId();
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(Id), lastUpdated = file.getLastUpdated();
  var fileOwner = file.getOwner().getEmail();

  // arrays with label and result names
  var aNames = ['File name', 'File Id', 'File Owner', 'Last updated by'];
  var aResults = [fileName, Id, fileOwner, lastUpdated];

  // create Ui  
  var Ui = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Quick Parts').setWidth(450);
  var vPanel = Ui.createVerticalPanel().setId('vPanel').setSize(450, 100);  
  var fTable = Ui.createFlexTable()
    .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse');

  // create labels
  for(var i=0, iLen=aNames.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    fTable.setWidget(i, 0, Ui.createLabel(aNames[i]));
    fTable.setWidget(i, 1, Ui.createLabel(aResults[i]));
  }

  // add to Ui
  vPanel.add(Ui.createLabel().setText("Document Property")
    .setStyleAttribute('font-size','175%'));
  vPanel.add(fTable);
  app.showSidebar(Ui.add(vPanel));
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm unfamiliar with `Quick Parts` specifically, but as to whether or not you can use macros in Google docs, they call them scripts, and you can access the script manager to make/edit scripts from `Tools->Script Manager` from inside a Google spreadsheet.

Comment: Is it available not in the spreadsheet? I need it in the docs.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Jacob's answer is going to be your better bet then for sure.