# Create help pop-up in Google Document using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to create a Google Document that has complex questions we ask clients.  I want to add a link at the end of each question that will launch a pop-up for additional information.

I currently have a .gs file that houses the script below:

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Help File.html')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, <b>Hello World!</b> );
  }
```

I also have a .html file with the following code:

```
< div>
Hello, world! 

< input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
< /div>}
```

Is there a way to embed this into a link on the Google Doc?  Currently, I am able to click "Run" from the Google Apps Script to make the pop-up window work.

Comment: Couldn't you copy the URL of the running script window, and use that as a link in your Google Document?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The URL of the script window shouldn't be accessible by anyone.  The pop-up window doesn't have a URL.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Ah, you're right. With `.showModalDialog()` there's no separate window with its own URL. See my answer below.

Comment: I would go for the sidebar, see answer I gave on that: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45980/29140

Answer (score 2):

You could [deploy your script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps), which implies implementing a `doGet()` method. In this method, you define your HTML content.

You can then access your script by the URL that is displayed in the *Deploy as web app* dialog. This URL could then be used in a link in your document.

However, the web app content is not displayed in a pop-up, so this might not solve your problem completely. You might want to create a *sidebar*. See [the documentation for this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs).